# Answer environment should give different font and different size I want. How can I do?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, exam, answers

I am working with this codes for my Question paper.

```
\documentclass[10.5pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam}

\newbox\allanswers
\setbox\allanswers=\vbox{}


\newenvironment{answer}
{%
    \global\setbox\allanswers=\vbox\bgroup
    \unvbox\allanswers
}%
{%
    \bigbreak
    \egroup
}

\newcommand{\showallanswers}{{Answe Key:\\ \par\unvbox\allanswers}}
% End Phil's answer


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question First Question
\begin{answer}
\thequestion Answer for the first question.
\end{answer}

\question Second Question
\begin{answer}
\thequestion Answer for the second question
\end{answer}
\end{questions}
\showallanswers
\end{document}
```

> I want my answers must be in different font and different font size.
>
> How I can do this??

Comment: try, for example, `\large\itshape` before `\unvbox\allanswers`

Comment: Which font, and which font size, do you want to use?

Comment: any other font in the true type font family. may be times new roman  with the size 13@mico

Comment: \large\itshape didnt work..@touhami

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't go the `\vbox` way. I prefer adding tokens and delivering at the end, so you can suitably define the output at the spot.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{environ,etoolbox}

\newcommand\allanswers{} % initialize
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{answer}
 {%
  % we want to expand \thequestion
  \protected@edef\BODY{\BODY}%
  % just expand once \BODY; \noexpand is in case \par is not the primitive
  \xappto\allanswers{\expandonce{\BODY}\noexpand\par}%
  \bigbreak
 }
\makeatother
\newcommand{\showallanswers}{%
  Answer Key:\par\nopagebreak\medskip
  {\setlength\parindent{0pt}\footnotesize\allanswers}%
}
% End Phil's answer


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question First Question
\begin{answer}
\thequestion. Answer for the first question.
\end{answer}

\question Second Question
\begin{answer}
\thequestion. Answer for the second question
\end{answer}
\end{questions}
\showallanswers
\end{document}
```

[image]

With your code (and `\vbox`) just add `\footnotesize` (or the size you want) after `\vbox\bgroup`.